# Errors occurred during magento installation

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to install magento 1.x on my centos machine. After dowloading and extracting magento i faced this errrors

```
Warning: include_once(Mage/Core/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/xxxx/app/Mage.php on line 50

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Mage/Core/functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/home/username/php') in /home/xxxx/app/Mage.php on line 50

Warning: include_once(Varien/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/xxxx/app/Mage.php on line 51

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Varien/Autoload.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/home/username/php') in /home/xxxx/app/Mage.php on line 51

Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Autoload' not found in /xxxx/app/Mage.php on line 54
```

I tried to run `php shell/compiler.php compile` the  the errors disappeared and the installation page appeared but without any next or back buttons.
How can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure on the new server , you have permissions to open and rewrite files. some mangento extensions require full permissions before installations.

Comment: Files have 777 permissions :)

Comment: Try to see of the file you trying to open is in correct directory